# Convert object of anyonymous type to a specific object in VB.NET without late binding

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, casting

we have a product where we can run VB.NET functions within a C# API. We can pass arguments to these VB.NET functions with an Object[]. Lets say we have the following invocation within the C# API where we pass 3 Parameters to a VBFunction:

```
var scriptParameters = new object[]
{
    new List<Object>() 
    {
        new { FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "King" },
        new { FirstName = "Aron", LastName = "Lee" },
        new { FirstName = "Gabbi", LastName = "Cole" },
    },
    "Managers",
    "de-DE"
};

var scriptResult = scriptRunner.Invoke("VBFunction", scriptParameters);
```

Now the first argument -- a List of Objects with Property FirstName, LastName -- is received by the VBFunction as a List of anonymous objects. These anonymous objects should be converted into an Object that is known to the VBFunction in order to be able to work with these objects. For a reason, we cannot set Option Strict off in the code or the compiler in order to use late binding.

Using CType() in order to cast the anonymous object into a similar type in VB.NET didn't worked either and raised an exception.

Do you know an elegant way to transform these anonymous objects into a useful object in the VB.NET script?

Best regards

Comment: You can't cast something as a type that it isn't. Casting is not a conversion of an object to a different type but rather a conversion of the type of the reference used to refer to that object. If an object is an anonymous type then that's the type it is. If you want an object of a different type then you need to create a new object and copy the data from the existing object.

Comment: Seeing the definition of VBFunction and the the class def of the type it is expecting would help!

Comment: I believe that the wording you used in your question is not accurate. You're trying to convert an object of type `Object` to an object of a specific anonymous type, not the other way around. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can hack your way around this by creating a dummy variable and a function that infers the target type from that variable. The function would look something like this:

```
' WARNING: This will throw an InvalidCastException if the underlying type
'          of `value` is not `T`.
Public Function IndirectCast(Of T)(value As Object, inferTypeFrom As T) As T
    Return DirectCast(value, T)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim list =
    New List(Of Object)() From
    {
        New With {.FirstName = "Dave", .LastName = "King"},
        New With {.FirstName = "Aron", .LastName = "Lee"},
        New With {.FirstName = "Gabbi", .LastName = "Cole"}
    }

Dim dummy = New With {.FirstName = String.Empty, .LastName = String.Empty}
Dim anonymousObj = IndirectCast(list.First(), dummy)

Console.WriteLine(anonymousObj.FirstName) ' Outputs: "Dave".
```

Or to cast the entire list:

```
Dim dummy = New With {.FirstName = String.Empty, .LastName = String.Empty}
Dim newList = list.Select(Function(obj) IndirectCast(obj, dummy)).ToList()

Console.WriteLine(newList.Last().FirstName) ' Outputs: "Gabbi".
```